# execute another function within function with data variables

Tags: php, codeigniter

need help on this one:

here's a my sample code,
i would like to add a validation message if a preg_match occurs:
pls. see inline comments for more details..

```
public function supplier_entry()
{
    if (preg_match("/[\'^£@&*...etc.../", $this->input->post('supplier')))
    {  

    //add or pass validation message, ex. $msg = 'Invalid Supplier Name';  
    // i tried $this->supplier_entry_form($msg); but its not working.  

        $this->supplier_entry_form();

    }else{
        $post_data = array(
        'supplier_name' =>$this->input->post('supplier'),
        'user' => $this->input->post('user'),       
        'trx_id' =>$this->input->post('trx_id'),
        );  

        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $this->load->model('product_model');

        $this->product_model->add_new_supplier($post_data);
        $user_data['trx'] = 'Supplier Entry';
        $user_data['username'] = $this->user_model->user_info();
        $trx_data['supplier'] = $this->product_model->get_supplier_list();  
        $trx_data['msg'] = 'Supplier Posted.';  


        $this->load->view('header',$user_data);     
        $this->load->view('item_supplier', $trx_data);              
    }
}
```

thanks in advance..

```
    public function supplier_entry_form()
{
    $this->load->model('user_model');
    $this->load->model('product_model');

    $user_data['username'] = $this->user_model->user_info();
    $user_data['trx'] = 'Supplier Entry';   
    $trx_data['supplier'] = $this->product_model->get_supplier_list();

    $this->load->view('header', $user_data);                      
    $this->load->view('item_supplier', $trx_data);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the method `supplier_entry_form()`?

Comment: Use the form_validation and a callback function, it's laid out pretty clearly in the user guide. You just make the preg match it's own function then call that function in the form validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the built in form validation.

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules($this->input->post('supplier'), 'Supplier', 'trim|callback_pregMatchSupplier');
if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE)
{
    $this->supplier_entry_from();
}
// continue code here if validation passes.


function pregMatchSupplier()
{
    if (preg_match("/[\'^£@&*...etc.../", $this->input->post('supplier')))
    {
       return FALSE;
    } else {
       return TRUE;
    }
```

Then in the view you echo out the validation errors:

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
```

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html